# How can I sort given a specific order that I provide

Tags: python, os.path, ends-with

I am trying to sort files in a directory given their extension, but provided an order that I give first. Let's say I want the extension order to be

```
ext_list = [ .bb, .cc , .dd , aa ]
```

The only way that I can think of would be to go through every single file 
  and place them in a list every time a specific extension is encountered.

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory): 
     if file.endswith( '.bb') --> append file
     then go to the end of the directory
     then loop again
     if file.endswith( '.cc')  -->append file
     and so on...
return sorted_extension_list
```

and then finally

```
        for file in sorted_extension_list :
            print file
```

Comment: Why are you not getting the whole list in one shot and then check the extension of each? Doing so you will get only one time the complete list and you can work on that. Hope this help to get your idea done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted()` with a custom key:

```
import os

my_custom_keymap = {".aa":2, ".bb":3, ".cc":0, ".dd":1}
def mycompare(f):
    return my_custom_keymap[os.path.splitext(f)[1]]

files = ["alfred.bb", "butters.dd", "charlie.cc", "derkins.aa"]

print(sorted(files, key=mycompare))
```

The above uses the mycompare function as a custom key compare.  In this case, it extracts the extension, and the looks up the extension in the `my_custom_keymap` dictionary.

A very similar way (but closer to your example) could use a list as the map:

```
import os

my_custom_keymap = [".cc", ".dd", ".aa", ".bb"]
def mycompare(f):
    return my_custom_keymap.index(os.path.splitext(f)[1])

files = ["alfred.bb", "butters.dd", "charlie.cc", "derkins.aa"]

print(sorted(files, key=mycompare))
```

Comment: thank you!. your extension is only a single character though, does it matter if mine are 2 or 3?

Comment: `my_custom_keymap = {key:value for value, key in enumerate(ext_list)}` `key=lambda f: my_custom_keymap[os.path.splitext(f)[1]]`

Comment: @Pythus - nope, the extensions can be any length, which you've probably figured out by now.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way of doing it:

```
files = []

for _, _, f in os.walk('directory'):
    files.append(f)

sorted(files,key=lambda x: ext_list.index(*[os.path.basename(x).split('.',1)[-1]]))

['buzz.bb', 'foo.cc', 'fizz.aa']
```

Edit: My output doesn't have `dd` since I didn't make a file for it in my local test dir. It will work regardless.

Comment: @bernie what is this sorcery?!

Comment: `files.append(files)` ? did you mean `files.append(file)` ? it's like you re appending the list to itself? also, i get an error stating that one extension that i defined does not exist

Comment: @Pythus it was a typo, fixed

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
# List you should get once:
file_list_name =['mickey.aa','mickey.dd','mickey_B.cc','mickey.bb']
ext_list = [ '.bb', '.cc' , '.dd' , '.aa' ]

order_list =[]
for ext in ext_list:
    for file in file_list_name:
        extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
        if extension == ext:
            order_list.append(file)
```

order_list is what you are looking for. Otherwise you can use the command sorted() with key attribute. Just look for it on SO!

Answer (score 1):

Using `sorted` with a custom key is probably best, but here's another method where you store the filenames in lists based on their extension. Then put those lists together based on your custom order.

```
def get_sorted_list_of_files(dirname, extensions):
    extension_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for _, _, files in os.walk(dirname):
        for filename in files:
            extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
            extension_map[extension].append(filename)
    pprint.pprint(extension_map)
    sorted_list = []
    for extension in extensions:
        sorted_list.extend(extension_map[extension])
    pprint.pprint(extensions)
    pprint.pprint(sorted_list)
    return sorted_list
```